# Understanding how audio/video chat works in the iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, chat

I am really looking forward on creating a **chat application** which features basic implementation of text chatting, as well as advanced features of **audio/video** chatting. I have clearly understood how to implement text chatting feature using [**push notification**](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12).

Now I am heading towards implementation of audio/video chatting in my application. I Googled around to see some samples for the same. I found [**Voice chatting**](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43756), [**idoubs**](http://code.google.com/p/idoubs/) and a couple of more sources, but ended on a negative note. What I realized is I am not sure of what actually happens during a audio/video chat. What are the background activities which take part when user is chatting.

I believe, if I understand the process behind the **audio/video** chat, I may implement it in a way I too understand.

So, if anyone among you has a brief/detail knowledge regarding audio/video chat, kindly share it with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A really brief audio/video starter would be the camera basically takes a series of images incredibly quickly and stores them to a buffer, these are then encoded into a specific format to be sent to a receiving device, which gets the video, stores it into a buffer and runs it through a decoder so it understands what the video it's received is. The decoder then passes the unencoded video frames to a specific view which constantly reloads the image which creates your video.

There's a bit more to it than that, but that's as basic as video comes. Audio works the same way pretty much, encoders and decoders do the grunt work of getting the sent content into an understandable output.

Comment: Is encoding and decoding of sequence of images supported by IOS or we need to import some framework?

Comment: There's various bits of functionality throughout the SDK that would allow you to do it, components for video playback and components for AV input (which is what the camera basically is).